# Using a rotation matrix opencv

Tags: opencv, matrix, rotation

I have a rotation matrix from the function Core.Rodrigues in opencv. I want to rotate a point located at (0, 0, 1) about the origin by this rotation matrix. How do I do this to get the new location of the point?

```
   Mat rmat= new Mat();
   Calib3d.Rodrigues(rvec, rmat); //rvec is the rotation vector from solvepnp
   double[] p= {0, 0, 1};
   Scalar scalar= new Scalar(p);
   Mat point= new Mat(1, 3, CvType.CV_64F, scalar);
   Mat newpoint= new Mat();
   Mat empty= new Mat();
   Core.gemm(point, rmat, 1, empty, 0, newpoint);
```

newpoint has 0, 0, 0 for the result, when I know that that is wrong

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to rotate a point about the origin is to premultiply it with the rotation matrix.  I am not familiar with Core.gemm.  Here is a more transparent way of doing this.

```
Mat rmat= new Mat();
Calib3d.Rodrigues(rvec, rmat); //rvec is the rotation vector from solvepnp
Matx33f rotation_matrix = rmat;
Matx31f original_point(0,0,1);
Matx31f rotated_point = rotation_matrix*original_point;
```

This should be much easier to debug.  Check the values stored in rotation_matrix, make sure they are initialized to reasonable values (the contents of Matx can be seen in debugger).  You can look at the values and do the multiplication yourself to double check if you like.  The process should be entirely transparent.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, is it a coincidence that you define your point p and then never use it again? Also, that you create a Scalar object with values from your Matrix points, and then set the values of points with that scalar? Perhaps this is the source of your errors.

Comment: No, when writing this I changed the variable names to make it easier to understand for the reader and I just made a mistake. The actual code is now the same as it reads above. Sorry for the mistake.