# OpenCV: apply Rotation matrix from Rodrigues() to a point

Tags: python, opencv, rotation

I have obtained a Rotation Matrix from Rodrigues() and I want to apply it to a point `[1,0,0]` in order to find its coordinates in Camera System (ignoring for the moment Translation vector)

How can I do that in Python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704221/using-a-rotation-matrix-opencv

Comment: Hi, this solution is not in Python. I'm afraid I'm getting stuck with some details related to matrix multiplication in Python....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found a solution that seems to work.
Here is sample code to transform point **(1,0,0)**:

```
# Computing rotation matrix
rotation_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs, rotation_matrix)
#Apply rotation matrix to point
original_point = np.matrix([[1],[0],[0]])
rotated_point = rotation_matrix*original_point
```

Comment: Hi, could you add in the setting of rvecs?

Comment: I've obtained rvecs from cv2.SolvePnP. Here's the line of code I've used:

ret,rvecs, tvecs = cv2.solvePnP(np.array(obj_points, dtype="double"), np.array(img_points, dtype="double"), camera_matrix, dist_coefs)